# Cannot Get JSON to Serialize in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have been able to get this to work before but for whatever reason I'm not able to get it work in this particular case and it's driving me crazy.

Here is the JSON I'm getting (using Toggl API):

```
{
  "total_grand": 1112836000,
  "total_billable": 598417000,
  "total_currencies": [
    {
      "currency": "USD",
      "amount": 1154.11
    }
  ],
  "total_count": 2,
  "per_page": 50,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 445687319,
      "pid": 21026846,
      "tid": 10185176,
      "uid": 2317636,
      "description": "Just doin' it...",
      "start": "2016-09-14T10:17:42-04:00",
      "end": "2016-09-14T10:19:13-04:00",
      "updated": "2016-09-14T10:12:08-04:00",
      "dur": 91000,
      "user": "UserName",
      "use_stop": true,
      "client": null,
      "project": "My Project",
      "project_color": "12",
      "project_hex_color": "#094558",
      "task": "New Task",
      "billable": 10.11,
      "is_billable": true,
      "cur": "USD",
      "tags": []
    },
    {
      "id": 445687306,
      "pid": null,
      "tid": null,
      "uid": 2317636,
      "description": "",
      "start": "2016-09-14T10:17:39-04:00",
      "end": "2016-09-14T10:17:39-04:00",
      "updated": "2016-09-14T10:10:34-04:00",
      "dur": 0,
      "user": "UserName",
      "use_stop": true,
      "client": null,
      "project": null,
      "project_color": "0",
      "project_hex_color": null,
      "task": null,
      "billable": 0,
      "is_billable": false,
      "cur": "USD",
      "tags": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's the class I'm using to serialize against. I took the JSON above and pasted into Visual Studio 2015 as a class, but it made the `total_currencies` and `data` fields in the `Rootobject` into arrays (ie - `public Datum[] data { get; set; }` which I believe I am supposed to change into `List<T>` as shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TogglApp1
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public int total_grand { get; set; }
        public int total_billable { get; set; }
        // public Total_Currencies[] total_currencieis { get; set; }
        public List<Total_Currencies> total_currencies { get; set; }
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        // public Datum[] data { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
    public class Total_Currencies
    {
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public float amount { get; set; }
    }
    public class Datum
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int? pid { get; set; }
        public int? tid { get; set; }
        public int uid { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated { get; set; }
        public int dur { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public bool use_stop { get; set; }
        public object client { get; set; }
        public string project { get; set; }
        public string project_color { get; set; }
        public string project_hex_color { get; set; }
        public string task { get; set; }
        public float billable { get; set; }
        public bool is_billable { get; set; }
        public string cur { get; set; }
        public string[] tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the C# code I'm (trying) to use to match these up...

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace TogglApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ENTER THE TEST TYPE
            // 1 = ENJOY SUCCESS WITH CONTENT FROM TOGGL API
            // 2 = THIS CODE TOYS WITH YOUR LIFE UNTIL THERE IS NONE LEFT
            // 3 = THIS CODE IS A GRAVEYARD OF BURIED HOPES AND DREAMS
            //
            int intTestType = 3;
            string strAuthCode = "[YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE]";

            var client = new RestClient("https://www.toggl.com");

            var request = new RestRequest("/api/v8/workspaces");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {strAuthCode}");
            request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            switch (intTestType)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.Write("Getting API Data via RestSharp...");

                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                        var content = response.Content;

                        // THIS WORKS - I AM GETTING THE CORRECT CONTENT
                        Console.WriteLine(content);

                        Console.ReadLine();

                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        Console.Write("Serializing API Data using RestSharp...");

                        var response1 = client.Execute<Rootobject>(request);

                        // THIS DOES NOT WORK - `data1` IS ALWAYS NULL
                        var data1 = response1.Data;

                        Console.Write("DONE! Check it!");

                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Console.Write("Serializing API Data using MakeRequest...");

                        string[] strAuth = new string[] { "Authorization", $"Basic {strAuthCode}" };

                        string[][] myHeaders = new string[][] { strAuth };

                        var response2 = MakeRequest<Rootobject>("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces", myHeaders);

                        // THIS DOES NOT WORK - `data2` IS ALWAYS NULL
                        var data2 = response2.data;

                        Console.Write("DONE! Check it!");

                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
        public static T MakeRequest<T>(string strUrl, string[][] strHeaders, string strRequestMethod = "GET") where T : class
        {
            // NOTE PARAMETERS ARE PASSED IN QUERYSTRING INSIDE URL

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Method = strRequestMethod;
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

                foreach (string[] strHeader in strHeaders)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add(strHeader[0], strHeader[1]);
                }

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new Exception(String.Format(
                        "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                        response.StatusCode,
                        response.StatusDescription));
                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                    object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
                    var jsonResponse = (T)objResponse;
                    response.Close();
                    return jsonResponse;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so neither method works and I'm almost certain it has something to do with the serialization class, but I don't get any errors like `ERROR: HEY YOUR CLASS DOESN'T MATCH UP WITH THE JSON I GOT FROM THE SERVER`... instead it just plain doesn't work and either fills the values with zeros or nulls.

Would love to get some help here... Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Per recommendation below, I pasted JSON into [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) and got the below response, basically the same as I had. I also updated to use this version in the serializer class and get the same results.

```
public class TotalCurrency
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int? pid { get; set; }
    public int? tid { get; set; }
    public int uid { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public int dur { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public bool use_stop { get; set; }
    public object client { get; set; }
    public string project { get; set; }
    public string project_color { get; set; }
    public string project_hex_color { get; set; }
    public string task { get; set; }
    public double billable { get; set; }
    public bool is_billable { get; set; }
    public string cur { get; set; }
    public List<object> tags { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int total_grand { get; set; }
    public int total_billable { get; set; }
    public List<TotalCurrency> total_currencies { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try pasting your JSON into this site and see if you get something different: http://json2csharp.com/#

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger - just tried it... same-same.

Comment: Tested with JSON.NET and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Plutonix - any chance you could elaborate on what that code looks like?

Comment: `var Currency = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrencyContainer>(jstr);` where `CurrencyContainer` is the same as your `RootObject`

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the JsonTextReader when dealing with incoming streams and had no problems...(without error handling)

```
public async Task<API_Json.RootObject> walMart_Lookup(string url)
    {
        lookupIsWorking = true;
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };
        using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient(handler))
        {

            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
            http.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
            url = String.Format(url);
            using (var response = await http.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                {
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                    {
                        var root = serializer.Deserialize<API_Json.RootObject>(jsonTextReader);
                       lookupIsWorking = false;
                        return root;

                    }
                }

            }

        }


    }
```

You also need to add the propoer attributes to your Json Classes:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class Rootobject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int total_grand { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int total_billable { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Total_Currencies> total_currencies { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Total_Currencies
{
    [DataMember]
    public string currency { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float amount { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Datum
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? pid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? tid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int uid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int dur { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string user { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public bool use_stop { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public object client { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string project { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string project_color { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string project_hex_color { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string task { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float billable { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool is_billable { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cur { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i notice you added `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` -- i have tried this both with and without these and seems to work (not in this case, but in others) -- when are they required and when are they not required?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know - just know that I had to add them and when I did it went from null/0 to good deserialization...